# Redefine \arraycolsep for particular environments

Tags: spacing, environments

How do I change `\arraycolsep` for a single environment?  E.g., I have `\arraycolsep` set so that the white spacing on either side of "=" in the equation array environment is not excessive.  However, this brings the columns of matrices in the `bmatrix` environment closer together as well.  I would like to redefine the matrix (`bmatrix`) environment so that it calls upon a local definition of `\arraycolsep` that is different than the one used globally (for equation arrays).

Comment: Are you using the `eqnarray` environment or that `array` environment to simulate an equation array? If its the former, please read [`\eqnarray` vs `\align`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5764) and use [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `\align` instead. Please clarify.

Comment: A [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) would certainly bring light into the darkness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [etoolbox package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to make adjustments to environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{bmatrix}{\setlength{\arraycolsep}{50pt}}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

The alteration takes place inside a group, so it will be undone when the environment ends.

Of course, as @Werner has pointed out, the solution to problems with `eqnarray` is to use the `align` environment from the [amsmath package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can explicitly set the column separation for them. To keep the spacing uniform in the document, you could specify the dimension in the preamble and then just use `\BigColSep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\BigColSep{\setlength{\arraycolsep}{50pt}}
\begin{document}

\[
\begingroup\BigColSep
\begin{array}{cc}
a & b 
\end{array}
\endgroup
\]

\end{document}
```

The `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` are only required if you mix some other arrays in this particular math display. If it consists only of `bmatrix`, they aren't needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the answer that really answers the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to adjust the `\arraycolsep`  *only* to obtain the correct spacing around the `=` sign (or other math operators), then you should consider an alternate approach:  Use `@{}` to eliminate the inter column spacing, and add and extra `{}` before the equal sign.  Compare the output of the two and you will see that the match.

### Notes:

- As others have mentioned if you are using `array` just to align elements in formulas you should consider other options such as `align`, and `alignat`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Spacing with array:
\[
\begin{array}{r@{}l}
    a &{}= b 
\end{array}
\]
And without array:
\[
  a = b
\]
\end{document}
```