# Is there a way to make difference tables in LaTeX? (Photo in post)

Tags: amsmath

Is there a way to make something like the following in LaTeX?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps a simple `array` environment would work here:

[image: screenshot of array environment, 7 columns, 3 rows]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array}{*{7}{c}}
        a_0 &         & a_1          &                   & a_2          &         & a_3 \\
            & a_1-a_0 &              & a_2-a_1           &              & a_3-a_2 &     \\
            &         & a_2-3a_4+a_0 &                   & a_3-2a_2+a_1 &         &     \\
            &         &              & a_3-3a_2+3a_1-a_0 &              &         &
    \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

I'd recommend taking a look at [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner)

If you wish to fix the `overful hbox warning` then you can, for example, adjust `arraycolsep` as follows:

```
\[
    \setlength{\arraycolsep}{4pt}%<----------- NEW BIT
    \begin{array}{*{7}{c}}
        a_0 &         & a_1          &                   & a_2          &         & a_3 \\
            & a_1-a_0 &              & a_2-a_1           &              & a_3-a_2 &     \\
            &         & a_2-3a_4+a_0 &                   & a_3-2a_2+a_1 &         &     \\
            &         &              & a_3-3a_2+3a_1-a_0 &              &         &
    \end{array}
\]
```

See [Redefine \arraycolsep for particular environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46284/redefine-arraycolsep-for-particular-environments), for example. Other options include using the `geometry` package to adjust your paper dimensions.

Comment: +1 You might want to additionally mention how one could decrease the value of `\arraycolsep` in order to get rid of the overfull box warning.

Comment: @leandriis good idea, many thanks :) I hope that the edit works :)

Answer (score 3):

I would do this with an `array` environment. Seven columns all centered. First row leave columns 2,4,6 empty. Second row 1,3,5,7 empty, third row you're only filling in columns 3 and 5 and fourth row just column 4.